# Problem with cmake and OpenCV 2.0 in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cmake, ubuntu-10.04

Goodnight, I'm working in a project where we use Cmake and OpenCV 2.0 in Ubuntu 10.04, everyone in the team(we are a micro-mouse contest team) can compile code just fine, but I cant.
This is what Cmake says to me:

```
tiago@tiago-laptop:~/bioloid/build$ cmake ..
-- Checking GNUCXX version 3/4 to determine  OpenCV /opt/net/ path
CMake Error at CMakeModules/FindOpenCV.cmake:348 (MESSAGE):
OpenCV required but some headers or libs not found.  Please specify it's
location with OpenCV_ROOT_DIR env.  variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:45 (FIND_PACKAGE)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

If I try to export the variable like this:

```
export OpenCV_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/lib
```

It keeps giving the same error, this is the output from pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

No one in the team knows what do do, I have already removed and re-instaled opencv, is there any chance that this is because I also have opencv 2.2 instaled in my computer?

Comment: Why did you try `/usr/local/lib` if the `pkg-config` tool reports `/usr/local/include/opencv`?

Comment: You might have already done this, but I just wanted make sure that you deleted the CMakeCache.txt file before running cmake again.

Comment: I have already tried /usr/local/include/opencv also, and all the combinations even from /usr/ up to the specific files, but it keeps saying the same, but thanks for the commentaries.

Comment: Have you tried to compile (and link) a basic test program using opencv without using cmake? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, I can compile programs with both opencv2.0 and 2.2. Maybe the problem is that opencv and opencv 2.2 are also in the /usr/local/include, one in /opencv and the other in /opencv. Maybe the best solution is a clean install of linux.

Comment: Will you reinstall your whole system because of that?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom Find macro to find opencv (CMakeModules/FindOpenCV.cmake) you should actually check which libraries this macro requires to find. As it looks like this macro is actually under your control, I would just add debug messages to its processing to find out at which point it fails. If the macro uses a call to MARK_AS_ADVANCED a good strategy could be print out all variables that are passed into this macro. All variables need to have a value that is not empty, false or XXX-NOTFOUND.

Apart from that, making the code of this find macro available to us would help in debugging.